# UK visa extension

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-extensions

I have a six-month UK visitor visa in my passport and the visa is going to expire on April 26, 2018. I have not used the visa to enter the UK yet and due to personal reasons, I will not be visiting the UK before the expiry of the visa. I plan to visit the UK in May 2018. Can I apply for an extension of the existing visa by 3 or 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you will need to apply for a new visa.

> **Extensions for long-term and multiple-entry visit visas ([Link](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF)):**
>
> If a visitor holds a long-term multiple-entry visa and they want to stay for longer than
> the visa expiry date, it is possible for them to apply to extend their leave for up to the
> maximum 6 months permitted for visitors (standard). For example, a visitor arrives in
> January and their long-term visit visa is due to expire in February. Provided the
> visitor meets the rules, they can extend for up to 6 months, until June, as a visitor
> (standard). A single entry or 6 month visa can also be extended to complete 6
> months’ in the UK as a visitor.

You will not qualify for the visa extension since [on this page](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/extend-your-visa) it states that you need to apply from inside the UK on the visa that needs extending (which you will not be).

> **Eligibility**
>
> You must apply while you’re still in the UK.

Comment: Unfortunately?  Extending while in the UK costs nearly a thousand pounds, while a new visa costs 89.  I would count myself fortunate if I were Obaid.

Comment: You are right there @phoog . That's an expensive extension. I'll change the wording.